# Keyframe animations and background-attachment: fixed issue on webkit

Tags: html, css

Hope someone can help me with this:

I'm working on a one page layout site with some keyframe animations and a couple of fixed background images that are overlayd when you scroll down.

Oddly (or not), i can't manage for the background-attachment:fixed to work with keyframes animations:

```
 <style>
.container{with:300px; height:400px}

.scaleAnimation {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-animation: scale 6s ease 3 normal;
    background-image:url("http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/images/3.jpg");
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.mask {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:300px
}
.mask1 {
    background-image:url(http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/images/1.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.mask2 {
    background-image:url(http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/images/2.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="scaleAnimation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mask mask1"></div>
        <div class="mask mask2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fpuLR/2/

If i remove the animation, the background-attachment works fine:

```
.scaleAnimation {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-animation: scale 6s ease 3 normal;
    background-image:url("http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/images/3.jpg");
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fpuLR/3/

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance,
Ku4ttro

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it's what I figured out when I came across the same problem as you - sorry it's months late, you might have never got this fixed, but this was unanswered so I figured I'd at least give it a go.

As far as I can tell, fixed elements get 'broken' when CSS animation/keyframes are used. I tried applying the same animations/keyframes(because I was using keyframes) to the div I was having problems with - and the fixed positioning worked! However it only seemed to keep it's fixed positioning while the same animation was being applied.

In my case I was fading an image in when the page loaded, so I was using this:

```
.fadeIn-Delay-2s {
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    -moz-animation-delay:2s;
    -o-animation-delay:2s;
    animation-delay:2s;
}

.fadeIn-3s {
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:3s;
    -o-animation-duration:3s;
    animation-duration:3s;
}

.fadeIn {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

My solution was to apply the same animation to it, but make the duration 0.01 seconds in length. It's fixed the problem for me, and until I figure out something different or find a jquery/javascript solution that provides the same smoothness that the CSS animation provides, I'm sticking with this.